# QApplication::setOverrideCursor не отрабатывает

Tags: c++, qt

Надо чтобы во время загрузки из файла данных, появляся курсор с кружком, обзначающий что идет загрузка. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
// создаю объект
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
// что-то с этим объектом делаю
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

Курсор не меняется при загрузке данных. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: приведите какой-то пример где не работает. В таком виде все нормально будет

Comment: Как в примере выше и не работает. 
Код следующий: Создаю объект класса, меняю курсор, загружаю данные из файла в БД (много данных, надо ждать пока загрузиться), делаю restoreOverrideCursor. 
После того как данные загрузились, появляется сообщение что данные загрузились и после закрытия этого окна, только меняется курсор. 
А надо чтобы я нажал загрузить данные у меня сменилось курсор на Qt::WaitCursor, данные загрузились, курсор стал обычным

Comment: Вся загрузка данных происходит внутри объекта класса (вызов одного метода), потоки там не используются

Comment: вполне себе работает
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        qDebug()<<i;
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();